# Can someone verify the reasons I give for using a "wa" and "ga" in this sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, は-and-が, cleft-sentences

> 私の生みの母は、若い未婚の日本人だったため、私を養子に出そうと決心したのです。彼女**が**こだわったの**は**、私の養子先は日本に住んでいる家族でなければ、ということでした。

The highlighted "は" looks to be there for *thematic reasons*?

The highlighted "ga" looks to be there for *neutral description*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason が is used here is because 彼女 is the subject of a **relative clause**. Relative clauses don't have topics, so が is used instead of は.

In a main clause, the が in 彼女が would likely be exhaustive rather than neutral (because it would be weird to have a neutral が attached to something already in the "universe of discourse"), but here in a relative clause that's not necessarily true.

The は, on the other hand, is a plain thematic は. It's a very common construction to have the topic は follow a nominalization:

> 禁煙したのはいいことだ。
>   It is good that you have quit smoking.

In other words, は is used here simply because there's no reason to use が.

Answer (score 0):

The GA you have highlighted makes the second sentence begin as: The THING that she was fixating on // obsessing about was...

Actually the key to unlocking this is the NOHA (NO WA) because こだわったの is a noun-ification of こだわった.

こだわったの refers to a noun now.  It is ...whatever she was obsessing over.

Answer (score 0):

### I Think You're Right

> 彼女**が**こだわったの**は**、私の養子先は日本に住んでいる家族でなければ、ということでした。

- **は** is marking the new topic that is developed in the following clause, so "thematic reasons" sounds good to me.
- **が** is used because the fact that it was **彼女** is secondary and supportive to the new topic, so "neutral description" or "theme-subordinate description" makes sense.